# What’s the difference between soldering iron wire wools?

Tags: soldering

What is the difference between the two different coloured wire wools for cleaning soldering iron tips?

[image]

[image]

Both are being sold online by many sellers and both claim to be made from copper.

Is one better than the other?

Is there a way to test/determine which metal they really are?

They look identical to kitchen scourers, except for their colour.

Related:

- [Brass wool versus steel wool](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/414919/brass-wool-versus-steel-wool)
- [Can I use steelwool for soldering iron cleaning](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/398336/can-i-use-steelwool-for-soldering-iron-cleaning)

Comment: The top one is clearly brass, not copper. The bottom one is probably copper. There's not really any reason you'd want to use copper over brass, though; I would use brass for its better oxidation resistance (don't want your tip cleaner to end up covered in verdigris).

Comment: Also, if those are very cheap, it's very possible they'll be just brass- or copper-plated steel, which will not do your soldering iron any favors. You can check if they are attracted to magnets; brass and copper are not, while most steels are.

Comment: Just buy from a reputable electronics vendor and you won't end up with painted bark or whatever. Never buy from scammer sites like Aliexpress or Ebay.